# How to display single category taxonomies in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to get the ID of single category in **category taxonomy** choosen when the user submits the form data

**Code:**

```
$options = array();
$terms   = get_resume_categories();
foreach ( $terms as $term )
    $options[ $term->slug ] = $term->name;
return $options;
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're trying to get a single term within the default "category" taxonomy. If you know the name of the category you want, you can use the [`get_term_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function.

e.g. If you wanted to get the term ID of the "Uncategorized" default category, you could do the following.

```
$search_field = 'name';
$field_value = 'Uncategorized';
$taxonomy_name = 'category';
$category = get_term_by( $search_field, $field_value, $taxonomy_name );
```

The ID would be stored in the `term_id` field of the returned object/array (depending on what you need). **Be sure to read the documentation page, and the warnings regarding the types of the returned fields.**